# String format, can't display decimals

Tags: c#, string, parsing, decimal, formatting

I'm creating a person register as a console application and i'm using several different datatypes wich i try to pass to a string.

Everything seem to be converted just fine exept decimal. The decimal "Average Income" won't display the number i write when i create objects out of the constructor. Why is this happening and is there an easy solution to this?

I'm guessing i need to convert the value in some way..

```
public class PersonRegistry : IPersonRegistry
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int YearOfBirth { get; set; }

    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public int Zip { get; set; }

    public string Occupation { get; set; }
    public decimal AvarageIncome { get; set; }

    public PersonRegistry(string Fname, string Lname, int year, string country, string city,
                          string state, int zip, string occupation, decimal income)
    {
        FirstName = Fname;
        LastName = Lname;
        YearOfBirth = year;

        Country = country;
        City = city;
        State = state;
        Zip = zip;

        Occupation= occupation;
        AvarageIncome = income;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("* First name: {0}\n* Last name: {1}\n* Born: {2}\n* Country: {3}\n* State: {4}\n* Oklahoma: {5}\n* Zip code: {6}\n* Occupation: {7:C}\n* Income: ",
                                FirstName, LastName, YearOfBirth, Country, City, State, Zip, Occupation, AvarageIncome);
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    PersonRegistry p1 = new PersonRegistry("Chuck", "Norris", 1940, "United States", "Ryan", "Oklahoma", 73565, "Actor", 1921.39m);
    PersonRegistry p2 = new PersonRegistry("Arnold", "Schwarzenegger", 1947, "Austria", "Thal", "Steiermark", 8113, "Actor, politician, bodybuilder", 3.289654m);

    var PersonRegList = new List<PersonRegistry>();
    PersonRegList.Add(p1);
    PersonRegList.Add(p2);

    foreach (var person in PersonRegList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(person);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Formatting is definitely your problem...

Comment: "... Income: {8}" maybe?

Comment: Lol that was embarassing, forgot the 8.. Sorry guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be :

```
return string.Format("* First name: {0}\n* Last name: {1}\n* Born: {2}\n* Country: {3}\n* State: {4}\n* Oklahoma: {5}\n* Zip code: {6}\n* Occupation: {7:C}\n* Income:{8} ",
                            FirstName, LastName, YearOfBirth, Country, City, State, Zip, Occupation, AvarageIncome);
```